# What language or application should be used in developing website to make it secure and make it tough for hackers to hack it

Tags: web

I am planning to get my website development outsourced to a third party developer. Need your help in deciding on how/ what technology to be used to make it very secure. Since I am not a techie I need the website developed in a way, so that it is easy for me to maintain it and modify content easily if required.

The main purpose of the website is to provide company information about services offered and then also to exchange documents and other file using FTP server. Will be sending out surevey and newletters sometime

Looking for your advice to guide me to the right direction

Comment: You're probably not going to get an answer here, as there is no single answer, but you're going to be better looking for a solid IT supplier than any technology.  Muppets using the best technology will still create shite.  Your requirements sound like you could get away with a simple CMS something like Drupal.

Comment: why do you need it so secure ? what are the risks ?

Answer (score 4):

As I already said on another answer, security is not a product, it's a process.

There isn't a 'secure' software or language. What makes your website/application secure is how it is developed and how the website is maintained.

There is no ready-made solution that, one time or another, won't be hacked.

If the people you are outsourcing to don't understand this, outsource to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Making your web server "hardened" against attack is best left to the expert sys-admins at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). However regardless of what technology you use, there is one **HUGE** thing an end user can do to protect her/his online assets:

[**USE STRONG PASSWORDS**](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/03/how-i%E2%80%99d-hack-your-weak-passwords/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a site secure using any technology/language/framework.

It's the code quality that makes a site insecure, not the technology/language/framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "correct" language to use -- it's possible to write an insecure website in any language.

The key is hiring staff that have the skill and experience in developing secure web solutions, and also making sure that the system is tested often by external specialists